# Static files are not loading in Django 1.8 templates

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I am using `Django 1.8` for my project but the problem is my static files are not loading into the template. I have followed each steps in detail, but still don't know why it is not loading.

**Template file**

```
 {% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <!-- This code is only meant for previewing your Reflow design. -->
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "css/boilerplate.css" %}'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "css/index.css" %}'>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
```

**Settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn', 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn', 'media')

STATICFILES_DIR = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

**Project Directory**

[image]

Could anyone tell me why the static files are not loading? The page source in browser is accurately showing the file path. When i click on it, it is showing me the css content but it is not loading when I run the server.

**Page Source:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <!-- This code is only meant for previewing your Reflow design. -->
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='/static/css/boilerplate.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='/static/css/index.css'>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
```

**urls.py file**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', AboutView.as_view(), name='index-template'),
    url(r'^register/', RegistrationListView.as_view(), name='register'),
    url(r'^form/', RegistrationForm.as_view(), name=''),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Inspect Element Result**:

[image]

Comment: Try running `python manage.py collectstatic`.

Comment: Done that! Still not working :/

Comment: @Jason `GET 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/boilerplate.css` is coming to be `NOT FOUND` not sure why!

Comment: Check spelling of [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS).

Comment: I have added my settings.py file, you can see it is correct. My `Debug = True` also.

Comment: You are missing a 'S' in the spelling of `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Correct that and run the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an 'S' in the spelling of [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS).

Once you correct that, do a `python manage.py collectstatic` and restart the dev server.